# mod_rewrite redirects to .html in error

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've just setup an AMP server on OSX 10.9 and have a bizzare problem which is not present on my live hosting server or my old WAMP server.

I want to redirect any URL that doesn't directly map to a file on the server to index.php. I'm using the following .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# prevent loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

when I try `http://example.com/example` there is no problem, but when I introduce another slash, for example, `http://example.com/example/`

I get the a 404 error `The requested URL /example.html/ was not found on this server.`

Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is related to enabling of `MultiViews` here. Turn it off by using this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.